# Tinymce 4 and combining js scripts

Tags: tinymce

Recently I changed to tinymce 4. I was happy to see you didn't have to put the tinymce.js script in the script_path parameter option anymore and could just include it together with other scripts I have on the page.

But, when I combine it with other scripts, tinymce doens't know where to find all the plugins, theme etc anymore.

Can someone tell me how this works in tinymce 4? Is there a script_path for tinymce 4? Also, is it possible to combine all the plugins and css you need in one package?

Answer (score 2):

TinyMCE has a custom packager, where you can choose to include everything in one js file. It's found at: https://www.tinymce.com/download/custom-builds/

After TinyMCE is combined with all the plugins you included on that page, it should work to combine with your own custom scripts with no problems.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but the packager forgets the language support but more important: tinymce loads the css. After combining it with other scripts it concats the current url with a relative path to the css which results in bad requests. Why can't tinymce leave the loading of the css up to the developer? Its silly to load the css from js.

Comment: That URL seems defunct now.